# Perl - Ordered multi-dimensional hash (use Hash::Ordered)

Tags: perl, hash

I am attempting to walking through a multi-dimensional hash in Perl, in the exact order I created it.  I am using Hash::Ordered, but cannot get it to work.

If I use Data::Dumper to print $MENU_ITEMS I see the hash elements I expect (see below), however, when I attempt to ingest them into $ITEM, it is blank.

I am sure I am doing something stupid, kindly help :)

```
use Hash::Ordered;
$MENU_SECTIONS = Hash::Ordered->new
    (
    'MENU_manage_properties' => 
        {
        'show_current_properties'  => 'Current Properties',
        'show_prospect_properties' => 'Prospect Properties'
        },
    'MENU_reports' => 
        {
        'some_report'             => 'Some report',
        'another_report'          => 'Another report'
        },
    'MENU_settings' => 
        {
        'settings_here'           => 'Settings',
        'more_settings'           => 'More Settings'
        }
    );

%MENU_SECTIONS_HTML = ();

use Data::Dumper;
print header();

$menu_iterator = $MENU_SECTIONS->iterator;
while( (my $MENU_SECTION, my $MENU_ITEMS) = $menu_iterator->() ) 5
    {
    print "<hr>my $MENU_SECTION, my $MENU_ITEMS<br>";
    print "Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:<br>";
    print Dumper $MENU_ITEMS;
    print "<br><br>";

    my $ITEM = Hash::Ordered->new(@MENU_ITEMS);
    $item_iterator = $ITEM->iterator;
    print "Dumper print of ITEM:<br>";
    print Dumper $ITEM;
    print "<br><br>";

    print "Dumper print of item_iterator:<br>";
    print Dumper $item_iterator;
    print "<br><br>";

    while( (my $OPERATION, my $TITLE) = $item_iterator->() ) 
        {
        print "my $OPERATION, my $TITLE<be>";
        }
    }
```

Output I am getting:

```
my MENU_manage_properties, my HASH(0x43a21f0)
Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:
$VAR1 = { 'show_current_properties' => 'Current Properties', 'show_prospect_properties' => 'Prospect Properties' };

Dumper print of ITEM:
$VAR1 = bless( [ {}, [], undef, 0, 0 ], 'Hash::Ordered' );

Dumper print of item_iterator:
$VAR1 = sub { "DUMMY" };

my MENU_tenants, my HASH(0x4397b80)
Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:
$VAR1 = { 'show_current_tenants' => 'Current Tenants', 'show_prospect_tenants' => 'Prospect Tenants' };

Dumper print of ITEM:
$VAR1 = bless( [ {}, [], undef, 0, 0 ], 'Hash::Ordered' );

Dumper print of item_iterator:
$VAR1 = sub { "DUMMY" };

my MENU_buyers, my HASH(0x4317590)
Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:
$VAR1 = { 'show_prospect_buyers' => 'Prospect Buyers', 'show_current_buyers' => 'Current Buyers' };

Dumper print of ITEM:
$VAR1 = bless( [ {}, [], undef, 0, 0 ], 'Hash::Ordered' );

Dumper print of item_iterator:
$VAR1 = sub { "DUMMY" };

my MENU_reports, my HASH(0x43175f0)
Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:
$VAR1 = { 'some_report' => 'Some report', 'another_report' => 'Another report' };

Dumper print of ITEM:
$VAR1 = bless( [ {}, [], undef, 0, 0 ], 'Hash::Ordered' );

Dumper print of item_iterator:
$VAR1 = sub { "DUMMY" };

my MENU_settings, my HASH(0x4317650)
Dumper print of MENU_ITEMS:
$VAR1 = { 'more_settings' => 'More Settings', 'settings_here' => 'Settings' };

Dumper print of ITEM:
$VAR1 = bless( [ {}, [], undef, 0, 0 ], 'Hash::Ordered' );

Dumper print of item_iterator:
$VAR1 = sub { "DUMMY" };
```

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings`. Always. You wrote `@MENU_ITEMS` instead of `@$MENU_ITEMS`; `strict` would have warned you.

Comment: I already tried that, perl returns "Not an ARRAY reference at ".  -- Just to confirm, you are suggesting I put that in this line, correct? my $ITEM = Hash::Ordered->new(@$MENU_ITEMS);

Comment: Right, `$MENU_ITEMS` is not an array ref, it's a hashref. I don't know what you wanted to do with it, but you should know. In any case, `@MENU_ITEMS` is not a variable that exists, so you should see that something is wrong with your code. Probably `%$MENU_ITEMS`.

Comment: (although it probably doesn't make much sense to convert an unordered hash into an ordered hash)

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your code. Declare all variables in the smallest possible scope using the syntax `my $variable`. After doing that and fixing those errors, come back to this question. Also, I am wondering why you are using `Hash::Ordered`, because it feels like an unnecessary complication. If you want to preserve order, use an array (with hash keys, or hash references). Using an external module, while possible, is likely unnecessary for you.

Comment: Using %$MENU_ITEMS appears to be a step in the right direction, however, the hash is not maintaining order.  EX:  'more_settings' is showing before 'settings_here'

Comment: That's because you created the hash using `{ ... }` whereas you should have used `Hash::Ordered->new` inside the first `Hash::Ordered->new`.

Comment: @Dada - thanks, you are probably correct, but I am not exactly sure how to implement what you are suggesting (Hash::Ordered->new inside the first Hash::Ordered->new).

Comment: `$MENU_SECTIONS = Hash::Ordered->new('MENU_manage_properties' => Hash::Ordered->new('show_current_properties'  => 'Current Properties', 'show_prospect_properties' => 'Prospect Properties'), ...)` and so on.

Comment: I'm wondering if you shouldn't be using arrays rather than hashes though.

Comment: @StevenCarlson Also, for future reference, if you are unhappy with an edit, use the Rollback feature to undo any changes. And don't add snarky remarks in the edit comments, that's just going to reflect badly on yourself (and its permanent, yay!).

Comment: Dada - I had considered that however, I am using the key as a lookup for other parts of my code. I have implemented your suggestion and it runs, only issue is now Hash::Ordered is complaining "new() requires key-value pairs at" on my $ITEM = Hash::Ordered->new($MENU_ITEMS); -- I switched back to just $ because %$ returned error not a hasref.

Comment: Dada - It works :) I'll update in a minute with the working code.  THANK YOU :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to @Dada for the help, here is the working code:

```
use Hash::Ordered;
$MENU_SECTIONS = Hash::Ordered->new
    (
    'MENU_manage_properties' => 
        Hash::Ordered->new(
        'show_current_properties'  => 'Current Properties',
        'show_prospect_properties' => 'Prospect Properties'
        ),
    'MENU_reports' =>
        Hash::Ordered->new(
        'some_report'             => 'Some report',
        'another_report'          => 'Another report'
        ),
    'MENU_settings' =>
        Hash::Ordered->new(
        'settings_here'           => 'Settings',
        'more_settings'           => 'More Settings'
        )
    );


$menu_iterator = $MENU_SECTIONS->iterator;
while( (my $MENU_SECTION, my $MENU_ITEMS) = $menu_iterator->() )
    {
    my $ITEM = Hash::Ordered->new($MENU_ITEMS->as_list);
    $item_iterator = $ITEM->iterator;

    while( (my $OPERATION, my $TITLE) = $item_iterator->() )
        {
        ## DO something with $OPERATION and $TITLE
        }

    }
```